# Hadoop installation via Cloudera manager

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to install hadoop via cloudera manager. 
After offline installed the CDH-5.12.0-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.29-el7.parcel and back to the cloudera manager. It disable to select the **hosts** and **continue** button
Please see the attached picture. Anyone who have ever occur this issue, And Is there any solution? thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the Cloudera Manager logo at the top. Do you see a cluster there?  I had something similar happen a while back and a cluster was created before CM could configure all the services.  If you see a cluster, you can delete the cluster and rerun the wizard by clicking Add Cluster.